# Formal sums vs. arbitrary sums for chain groups

Tags: algebraic-topology

We defined the $n$-chain group as follows,

$$C_n(X) = \bigg\{ \sum_{v \in V} n_v [v_1, \dots, v_n] : n_v \in \mathbb{Z}, \hspace{2mm} n_v=0 \hspace{2mm} \text{for all but finitely many} \hspace{1mm} n_v\bigg\}$$

I am not sure why it is important that $n_v=0$ for all but finitely many coefficients.

Is this the same thing as saying that $C_n(X)$ is a formal sum, and if so, why can it not be an arbitrary sum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible reason is that if we allowed infinite formal sums then it would be impossible to define the boundary map. Suppose our simplicial complex consists of all simplices of the form $[v_0,v_i]$ with $i\geq 1$. Consider the formal sum
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}{[v_0,v_i]}$$
The boundary of this linear combination would be
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}{([v_i]-[v_0])}$$
and this is not well-defined because the coefficient of $[v_0]$ would be $-\infty$.

The chain complex is defined as the free abelian group generated by the simplices, and this consists of all formal finite linear combinations of simplices.

Comment: Does the "formal" sum somehow imply that the linear combination will be finite? If we put the finite linear combination condition on a arbitrary sum wouldn't the boundary maps still be defined?

Comment: "Formal" simply implies that these aren't things that we'd normally be adding and we are forcing an addition operation on them by adding them together with integer coefficients without regard for the meaning of this. Formal sums can be finite or infinite, but for the case of a chain complex they will be finite.

Comment: Ok. If "formal" is nothing more than defining the group as you said above, then why when defining Borel-Moore homology groups does the local finiteness condition allow the use of arbitrary sums to define the chain group?

Comment: When the chain is locally finite, the example I gave won't occur because no simplex will be contained in infinitely many other simplices, so the boundary map will give linear combinations with integer coefficients.

Comment: Ok, so the "Formal" sum isn't what is making the group  We can still view it as a group even if it an arbitrary sum.

Comment: Yes. Then it would be isomorphic to the direct product of one copy of $\mathbb{Z}$ for every simplex. For finite linear combinations it is isomorphic to the direct sum.

Comment: Got it. Very helpful, thank you.

Comment: You're wlecome.